# STL List using c++ ....in passing array of pointer of list

Tags: c++, stl, linked-list, pass-by-reference

i am facing problem in passing STL list obj b reference, here is the code
using prototype

```
void input(list<string>& *x[])
```

declaring in main

```
list<string> *table[SIZE];
input(table);     //calling
```

any help would be apprecited.

Comment: Are you sure that you want `table` to be an array of pointers? It is hard to say without further information, but a `vector<list<string>>` or a `vector<list<string>*>` would be better in the vast majority of cases.

Answer (score 5):

Your function is attempting to take a pointer to a pointer to a reference to a `list<string>`. Your problem is that it is impossible to create a pointer to a reference.

You should instead try making a reference to an array of pointers to `list<string>`:

```
void input(list<string> *(&x)[SIZE])
```